# Not adding on to a textbox

Tags: c#

Hello guys basically i am in my first steps of C#, i have been doing for a few hours now. Coming from java i am picking this up fast but i have recently stumbled upon something that shouldnt be happening i think. I have this in a .cs called Input

```
        frmCodeGenerator f = new frmCodeGenerator();

    private void cmdOkay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        f.updateString(int.Parse(txtInput.Text));
        this.Hide();
    }
```

now the part thats not working is the f.updateString

Ive tried to use a numeric box but that didn't work either. But in frmCodeGenerator i have 4 buttons using the current updateString method itself and it seems to be functioning as i want it too. Could anyone care to explain to me why this isnt actually working.

here is my updateString method for anyone who needs it

```
        public void updateString(int amount)
    {
        g.generateNumbers(amount);
        txtOutput.Text = g.print.ToString();
        g.print.Clear();
    }
```

Yours.

Here are my two classes

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class frmCodeGenerator : Form
    {

        GenerateCode g = new GenerateCode();

        public frmCodeGenerator()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void codeGen_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtOutput.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 196);
        }

        private void char8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            updateString(8);
        }

        private void char16_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            updateString(16);
        }

        private void char32_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            updateString(32);
        }

        private void char64_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            updateString(64);
        }

        private void charInput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Input i = new Input();
            i.Show();
        }

        public void updateString(int amount)
        {
            g.GenerateCodes(amount);
            txtOutput.Text = g.print.ToString();
            g.print.Clear();
        }

        private void txtOutput_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

and the other class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    class GenerateCode
    {
        String[] avaliable = 
        { 
        "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H",
        "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P",
        "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X",
        "Y", "Z", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5",
        "6", "7", "8", "9"
        };

        public StringBuilder print = new StringBuilder();
        Random random = new Random();
        /**
         * Basic number generator with the amount which
         * is the number of times i add to the stringbuilder called print.
         * */
        public void GenerateCodes(int amount)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
            {
                print.Append(avaliable[random.Next(avaliable.Length)]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what does `not working` mean to you?  Can you provide us with what you expect to happen, and what is happening?

Comment: Are you actually displaying that instance of the `frmCodeGenerator` class?  Are you sure that you haven't created multiple instances but only shown one, so any changes will only be visible if they are made on that instance?

Comment: What's there in `f.updateString`?

Comment: What's `g.print` here? shouldn't you be storing the result of `g.generateNumbers(amount)` somewhere?

Comment: I have updated it, now there are the two classes

Comment: You said `f.updateString` not working. What do you mean by that? do you get error?

Comment: No no errors, it just dosnt change the txtOutput....in the char16 32 64 the txtOutput changes

Answer (score 2):

Let me piece together what you have:

An Input form with a textbox that allow you to enter numbers:

```
public class Input:Form 
{
    frmCodeGenerator f = new frmCodeGenerator();

    private void cmdOkay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        f.updateString(int.Parse(txtInput.Text));
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

And your main/start form `frmCodeGenerator` which has some textbox to show the generatedcode. You have one button from which you instantiate and show the Input form with this code:

```
    private void charInput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Input i = new Input();
        i.Show();
    }
```

And you want the code entered in the Input form to be shown in the frmGenerated form.

The problem is: You create a NEW instance of frmCodeGenerator in Input WITHOUT showing it. I assume you don't want to create a new Form but just re-use the existimg one.

You have two options: one is to make Input ShowDialog and grab the value from a property, the other is to hand a reference from `frmCodeGenerator` to you Input form.

### Option 1

Create a public property and call ShowDialog (to keep the focus on the Input form)

#### frmCodeGenerator changes

```
    private void charInput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Input i = new Input();
        i.ShowDialog();
        updateString(i.Value);
    }
```

#### Input changes

```
public class Input:Form 
{
    public int Value { get; private set;}

    private void cmdOkay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // improve to use Int32.TryParse
        Value = int.Parse(txtInput.Text));
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

### Option 2

Hand a link to the caller form...

#### frmCodeGenerator changes

```
    private void charInput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Input i = new Input(this); // provide a reference to the current form
        i.Show();
    }
```

#### Input changes

```
public class Input:Form 
{
    private frmCodeGenerator myFrmCodeGenerator; // hold the caller
    // extra constructor
    public Input(frmCodeGenerator frm)
    {
       myFrmCodeGenerator = frm;
    }   

    private void cmdOkay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // improve to use Int32.TryParse
        
        // call the method on our original form
        myFrmCodeGenerator.updateString(int.Parse(txtInput.Text));

        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

#### Option Not Likely

The fix with least amount of code to demonstrate what is going wrong in your current soution

```
public class Input:Form 
{
    frmCodeGenerator f = new frmCodeGenerator();

    private void cmdOkay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        f.updateString(int.Parse(txtInput.Text));
        // this will Show your newly created Form but now you have two of them...
        f.Show(); 
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```